# How to automatically change path in angular when scrolling

Tags: angular, angularjs, url-routing

[image]

I'm using angular 17, and I want to make a page that contains multiple components but each component can be accessed through a path (when clicking on the navigation menu it automatically scrolls there and changes the path of that specific component) [see the image above]

but when manually scrolling I also want it to be detected by the app and automatically change the path to the correct one according to the component being displayed

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to point to a specific location inside of a page, I think you should use [fragments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) instead of the path.

```
In computer hypertext, a URI fragment is a string of characters that refers to a resource that is subordinate to another, primary resource. The primary resource is identified by a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), and the fragment identifier points to the subordinate resource.

The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document. The generic syntax is specified in RFC 3986.[1] The hash mark separator in URIs is not part of the fragment identifier.
```

You can use an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when the component is inside of the viewport and when your fragment should change. Then use [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) of the [routers navigate method](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) to change the fragments.

Code for navigation should look similar to:

```
this.router.navigate(['.'], {
  fragment: 'about-me'
});
```